# Adding active class to list item according to the URL in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 3 list items and I want to add active class based on the URL. Here are my list items:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs my-4">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a routerLink='/' class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a routerLink='products' class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a routerLink='users' class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Users</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

What I want to do is, I want to activate products list item even though the URL is like this:
http://localhost:4200/products/1   or like this:  http://localhost:4200/products?page=2&order=newest

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}"`?

Comment: I changed products's exact false and it worked. Could you explain what does exact do?

Comment: `exact: true` matches only if the entire path is the exact match of the route, which you actually didn't want. `exact: false` does the opposite of it, i.e. matches partial routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` for every link, as it matches your link exactly and won't add active class if route is different even a param.

We add `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` normally for root('/') route as it is common route for other links as well.